# Malaysia Visa Run

Tags: visas, malaysia, visa-runs

I have been a student for 2 years in Malaysia and my student visa is set to expire on July 17th. I am planning to do a visa run on July 17th to Singapore and stay there for 3-4 days then come back to Malaysia. I am wondering if anyone has done this before and whether it should be done via airplane or bus. I also want to know if I should be aware of any risks of this besides being stranded in Singapore. This is my first time doing a visa run.

Comment: What's your citizenship? Can you get a student visa in Singapore, or are you going for something else?

Comment: [Related question here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/76151/6389). The law in Malaysia is that once your study period is finished you have to cancel your student visa and then exit the country. If you don't cancel you might have to bear fines. Though I knew somehow with student visa in the same situation left to Indonesia and came back after 5 days, they questioned him on the exit from Malaysia, but nothing bad happened and he got a 3 months visa.