# Can a 90-day visa-free visit to Malaysia be extended? (Australian passport)

Tags: malaysia, visa-extensions

I'm an Australian visiting Malaysia on the visa-free basis and recently faced my 90 days running out. I ended up doing a successful border run to Singapore and back but keep wondering whether an official extension form Malaysian immigration would've also been possible.

Often you can't extend when on a visa waiver or visa-free entry. But some countries do allow it. But when I start looking on the internet I immediately find very contradictory answers. Definite "no" and definite "yes":

[image: Google search results]

Does anybody know what the rules are in this "post COVID"?

It may well make a difference what country the traveller is from. I expect people from South Asia are more commonly suspected of working while on a tourist visa than people from "rich" western countries for instance. That could explain widely varying but still quite assertive results I found. But it could also be a difference between "visa waiver" vs "visa free" entry which are often conflated, and also with other "regular" types of visa.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76151/can-i-extend-my-stay-in-kuala-lumpur-malaysia-beyond-90-days-by-doing-a-visa-r

Comment: @Traveller I saw that one and in fact I ended up doing a visa run instead of trying to get an extension. But this question is not about visa runs, only about extensions.

Comment: FWIW, the UK gov advice is that visas for longer stays or for non-tourist purposes must be obtained from the nearest Malaysian diplomatic mission before you travel. I would expect to see an option to extend the 3 month entry on arrival permission mentioned, if one exists. Of course YMMV as an Australian citizen

Comment: @Traveller In my experience the information on the Australian government site for travellers is slightly less reliable than the information direct from the country in question. In this case I don't have the official Malaysian info to compare.